Unable to Configure SSIS Data Flow Transaction (SSIS 2022 Version)
I'm trying to utilize the built-in Transaction functionality without success. I've adhered to the MSFT Learn documentation and activated MSDTC on the database server, which is also hosting SSIS.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/commerce-server/dd327979(v=cs.95)?redirectedfrom=MSDN
Below is my test package configuration and the error message I received. It indicates that the data flow task cannot redirect errors while using a connection with a transaction.
Is this a recognized limitation of SSIS? Is there a workaround for scenarios that require the use of SSIS Transactions while leveraging Data Flows error redirection? Thank you!
My Test Package:
test_cf_img
test_df_img
Created a testing package that is attached above.
